# download files from a folder and list the download links to each file on a single wepage

Tags: html, servlets

I need to download files from a folder and for that i have created this servlet DownloadServlet.java

```
import java.io.*;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  

public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {  

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
        throws ServletException, IOException {  

 response.setContentType("text/html");  
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

 File f = new File("C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/data");

 File[] files = f.listFiles();

 for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

 String filename=files[i].getName();
 String filepath=files[i].getAbsolutePath();

 response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");   
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");   


 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);  


 int j;   
 while ((j=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {  
 out.write(j);   
 }   
 fileInputStream.close();   
 out.close();  
 }
 }  
 }
```

The above mentioned code is for the download procedure. 
The html file that i've created is as follows:

[image]

when run th html file on the server only one download link is shown and the first file in the folder is download.

Can anyone help as to how can i show links of all the file ????

Comment: what does it mean by *run th html file on the server*? html runs on client (browser)

Comment: both the links are pointing to same servlet.

Comment: @Braj sorry i meant browser and ignore the other link in the Html file. Now, Can u help me with my question ?

Comment: You can't download multiple files in one call to a servlet, unless perhaps your servlet creates a zipfile and serves that.